# Is my damaged Nikon D500 a write-off or repairable?

Tags: nikon, equipment-damage

I dropped my Nikon D500 from a height of approx. 5ft and it, along with my Sigma 150-600 lens, hit the tarmac hard. The lens broke into two pieces although the camera appears to have fared better. However, on closer inspection the lens mount has moved (it is no longer central); the lenses don't lock on; the diopter doesn't work; the SD card slot door is damaged and the body has superficial scuffing.

I'm wondering... is this camera a write off or is it repairable?

Comment: You'll likely get a more definitive answer from an authorized repair person who can tell you how much it will cost to fix and, therefore, whether you should repair or replace.

Comment: yes I am going to go down the insurance route,the lens and camera took a big impact and id rather it be written off as im worried that the camera wont function properly after the insurance companies technicians have fiddled with it. In future i think ill insure it with nikon. oh and thanks for your advice, the word authorized doesnt apply to the insurance companys repair staff i wouldnt think.

Comment: I'm sure the insurance company contracts the work out to a camera repair facility. While they might not be Nikon factory authorized, they might still be well qualified to repair your camera. If the mount flange has been moved to the point you can tell by looking with the naked eye it is probably not repairable, though.

Comment: no the company that is going to try and repair my equipment is a loss adjustment company called bevalued in the uk they say they have their own technicians that specialize in photographic equipment like nikon etc, I am very woried about this level of expertise being let loose on my d500 Im woried what camera I will get back

Comment: Nikon has made it pretty much impossible for anyone who isn't an authorized service depot to get parts.  If Bevalued doesn't fall into that category, they're not going to be able to repair it to factory spec.